# JQuery-Mobile collapsible expand/collapse event

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Does anyone know any other way to capture the event of expanding or collapsing a component marked with `data-role="collapsible"` apart from the `onclick` event of its header?

EDIT: I would like some kind of event that will also provide information about the expanded/collapsed state of the component.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

There are custom events for the `collapsible` blocks. You can bind to the `expand` and `collapse` events:

```
$('#my-collapsible').bind('expand', function () {
    alert('Expanded');
}).bind('collapse', function () {
    alert('Collapsed');
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6txWy/

Comment: Note: This is triggered before the div is actually expanded. So this will not work if trying to get the position of the div after it opened.

Comment: @Bot What are you trying to do that needs to get the position of the div element (I'm assuming you meant the collapsible content area)?

Comment: @Jasper I needed to get the collapsible div position so I could scroll it to the top of the screen.

Comment: @Bot Gotcha, what about setting a short timeout that will allow the widget to expand (and any other layout changes to settle) before getting its position? User's won't really notice a `50ms` delay which is less than two frames at 30fps.

Comment: That could work. I went ahead and just added the scrolling code into my click event after I call the `.trigger('expand');` command.

Comment: This works. Thank you. Odd, because their documentation states `$('.selector').on('collapsibleexpand', function(){});` and similar for `collapsiblecollapse`. :(

Comment: Watch out for "collaspible" instead of "collapsible" :)

Comment: Thank you, this is a very useful answer.

Answer (score 16):

In jQuery Mobile 1.4 there are the *collapsiblecollapse* and *collapsibleexpand* events. https://api.jquerymobile.com/collapsible/#event-collapse

```
$( ".selector" ).on( "collapsiblecollapse", function( event, ui ) {} );
```

Comment: This worked for me in contrary to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can bind any event you want, example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/9mDbh/    // Events
- http://jsfiddle.net/9mDbh/1/  // Touch Events

Demo:

- http://jsfiddle.net/9mDbh/5/

JS

```
$("div:jqmData(role='collapsible')").each(function(){
    bindEventTouch($(this)); 
});

function bindEventTouch(element) {
    element.bind('tap', function(event, ui) {
       if(element.hasClass('ui-collapsible-collapsed')) {
            alert(element.attr('id')+' is closed');
        } else {
            alert(element.attr('id')+' is open');
        }
    });
}
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="content">
        <div data-role="collapsible" id="number1">
           <h3>Header #1</h3>
           <p>I'm Header #1</p>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false" id="number2">
           <h3>Header #2</h3>
           <p>I'm Header #2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is another way to do this. I do not believe that you can utilize `animationComplete` in this case as described here:
http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html

Maybe you can utilize certain class changes on the specific elements, which in fact isn't better than binding an onclick event of the header.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [jQuery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a2/#docs/api/events.html) tap event. I haven't used it personally, but I hear it's similar to the `mousedown` event handler. If you gave a little more detail about why the onclick isn't working maybe we could help you out a little more.

Comment: The `onclick` works. It's just that I would like to use something different, maybe something that will also give information about the expanded/collapsed state of the component.