# Jquery Mobile collapsible event not firing

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to do sth similar like here: [JQuery-Mobile collapsible expand/collapse event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399882/jquery-mobile-collapsible-expand-collapse-event)

I can't get it to work! Even if I copy the code and put it in my site nothing happens, after clicking on the collapsible.

```
<div data-role="page" id="test">
    <div data-role="collapsible" id="my-collaspible">
        <h3>My Title</h3>
        <p>My Body</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the js code:

```
$('#my-collaspible').bind('expand', function () {
  alert('Expanded');
}).bind('collapse', function () {
  alert('Collapsed');
});
```

Any advice? I have no idea where the problem could be!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is ex : http:// jsfiddle.net/quangtuyn/s4k7d/

You can check agian

Hope it will be useful for you

Comment: I did not know that you have to use a $(document).ready(function

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Is it a typo?
"my-collaspible"?
Try changing the ID in the markup and jquery selector to the correct spelling

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need use collapse event

```
$("#my-collaspible").trigger("collapse");
```

and expand event

```
$("#my-collaspible").trigger("expand");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find element to which Jquery UI is bound to.

```
$("[data-role*='collapsible-set']").bind('expand', FixJQueryMobileUIFails)

function FixJQueryMobileUIFails(element) {
    StraightenColumnsforQueryUIHeaders(element);
    StraightenCornerNextToHeaderInLastTreeElement(element);
    RoundBottomCornerInLastTreeElement(element);
 }
```