# Collapisble Set, jQuery Mobile, inject AJAX content

Tags: jquery-mobile

Given a basic jQuery Mobile Collapisible Set, how can I get AJAX content before the toggle event fires?  I am using jQM to create the following:

```
<div id="test" data-role="collapsible-set" data-inset="false">
  <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" data-mini="true">
    <h2>Title #1</h2>
    <ul data-role="listview"></ul>
  </div>
  <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true" data-mini="true">
    <h2>Title #2</h2>
    <ul data-role="listview"></ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to be able to when a user clicks on the "toggle" fire of an AJAX call to get content from the server and place it in the correct ul.  I can figure out how to do everything except intercept the "click".  I have tried binding on both click and expand on the div's, h2's and even ul's.

I am looking for something like:

```
$('#test h2').live('click',function() {
    // do my AJAX call here to get li's to put in correct ul (assuming none exist)
});
```

Surely I am missing something super simple.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8404143/64262

Comment: Hmmm...wow I feel like an idiot.  I swear I tried that (not the same as a collapsible set), but it appears it might work.  I will come back and post if I get it to work completely.

Comment: The interesting bit is that I don't see that info in the current set of jqm docs. It may or may not work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok...Here is a working example (minus the AJAX).  The biggest drawback is that this only "fires" on expand.  But by then it has already expanded and thus currently shows a blank space.  What is really needed is a "before expanding" or "click" event so that you can inject the content you want and then the default can happen (changing icons, showing, etc).  Not sure how to go about proposing that...

http://jsfiddle.net/mfumm/

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
<div data-role="page" id="page">
  <div id="set" data-role="collapsible-set" data-inset="false"></div> 
</div>
$("#set div:jqmData(role='collapsible')").each(function () {
  $(this).bind('expand', function() { 
    if($(this).find('li').length < 1) {
      // do ajax call here to get data
      $(this).find('ul').append(items).listview('refresh');
    }
  });
});
$('#page #set li').live('click',function () {
  alert('Go to item');
});
```