# Click on jQuery Mobile collapsible-set?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, click

How to bind click on one lement of collapsible-set?

```
<div data-role="content">
   <div data-role="collapsible-set" data-theme="d" data-content-theme="d">
       <div data-role="collapsible" id="expand">
        <h3>header</h3>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#expand', function (e) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('ekb'); // my stuff
    });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pExFF/3/

Comment: It seems to work properly. what do you expect it to do ?

Comment: it doesn't show console.log

Comment: clicking on the "hh" section does log "ekb" in both safari in chrome in osx. what os/browser are you using ?

Comment: your fiddle is fine..it showsthe console.log in chrome..

Comment: I need it on click by header

Comment: I recommend the solution discussed here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399882/jquery-mobile-collapsible-expand-collapse-event

Answer (score 2):

It seems that because of the jQuery Mobile enhancements the action you bound to the click event is not triggered when you click on the header.
An option (not very pretty I admit) could be to bind the event to the proper DOM elements after the JQM enhancements has been made. If you do indeed intend to prevent default behavior (which will prevent collapsible from uncollapsing !), you could use code like this :

```
$(document).on('pageinit',function (f) {
  //pageinit event is triggered after the page is initialized

    $("#expand").find("*").click(function (e) {
      //apply to all descendant of your element "#expand a" selector would be sufficient to cover the header
         e.stopImmediatePropagation();
         e.preventDefault();
     console.log('ekb');
    });
});
```

The result is visible [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xmwGj/)