# How to be notified of a collapse for the Collapsible

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm trying to get notified when the Collapsible is expanded and collapsed but I cannot seem to find out how to get this to work.

As of now I cannot get any type of notification.

Any suggestions?

**Here is my code.**

--Imported jQuery

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
```

--Jquery

```
$("#my-collaspible").collapsible({
    expand: function (event, ui) {    
        alert('Expanded');
    }
 });
```

--HTML

```
<div id="my-collaspible" data-role="collapsible-set" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="b">

<div data-role="collapsible" id="divAuto" title="Automation">
    <h3>Automation</h3>
    <article style="height:600px"></article>
</div>
<div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a" title="Collaboration">
    <h3>Collaboration</h3>
    <article></article>
</div>
<div data-role="collapsible" title="Accessibility">
    <h3>Accessibility</h3>
    <article></article>
</div>
<div data-role="collapsible" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="a" title="Company Management">
    <h3>Company Management</h3>
    <article></article>
</div>
```

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/8404143/961695

Comment: I've tried all those, for some reason I'm missing something somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To bind an event listener to the expand event:

```
$( ".selector" ).on( "collapsibleexpand", function( event, ui ) {
    console.log(event);
} );
```

api: [event-expand](http://api.jquerymobile.com/collapsible/#event-expand)