# How to get an "collapse" event of a .ui-collapsible from jQuery Mobile before it collapses

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-mobile

I do:

```
$( ".ui-collapsible" ).on("collapse", onCollapse );
```

then:

```
var onCollapse = function(e) {
    // close all open input fields on collapse
    $(this).find( ".closeable [data-role='button']" )
           .filter(":visible")
           .trigger( "click" , "enter" );
};
```

But the collapsible element is already collapsed, so there are no visible elements anymore.

Is there a way to get this event before the actual collapsing?

Comment: No, unless you extend the widget to support new events. Which version of jQuery Mobile are you using? Are you also really binding to `collapse` instead of `collapsiblecollapse`?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I'm binding to collapse. Thx anyway.

Comment: Another option is to collapse/expand them manually, on clicking on the collapsible's header.

Comment: Can you post a sample of your html/collapsible markup?

Comment: @Omar, I found a workaround. I add an attribute visible="true" to an open element, and the change the codelike this:

`var onCollapse = function(e) {
 // close all open input fields on collapse
 $(this).find( ".closeable[visible='true'] [data-role='button']" )
.trigger( "click" , "enter" );
};`

Answer (score 0):

I actually didn't check offering enough to figure out whether it triggered before collapse or not, but you can still try it:

```
 $('#my-collaspible').bind('expand', function () {
    alert('Expanded');
 }).bind('collapse', function () {
    alert('Collapsed');
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6txWy/2062/

from [JQuery-Mobile collapsible expand/collapse event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399882/jquery-mobile-collapsible-expand-collapse-event)