# Updating a DIV inside a Collapsible in JQuery Mobile only when the Collapsible is opened (eg. load on demand)

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, external, jquery-mobile-collapsible

I'm trying to execute a call to an external program to create content in a DIV inside a collapsible in JQuery Mobile, to have some code run when a div in a JQM collapsible appears when the collapsible is opened. I'm trying to use the jquery.appear plugin (https://github.com/morr/jquery.appear) as follows:

```
<div id="coll2" data-role="collapsible" data-mini="true" data-inset="false" data-iconpos="right">
  <h1>Collapsible 1</h1>
  Collapsible Title! 
  <div id="2wrapper"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document.body).on('appear', '#2wrapper', function() {
  // this element is now inside browser viewport

    alert("Script running");
    $("#2wrapper").load('some-external-program-content.cgi');

});

</script>
```

I'm obviously missing something because the div isn't updating when the collapsible is opened. Would appear work in this instance? Or is there a more effective way to achieve this "on demand" loading of the content in the collapsible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any plugin, just use the [expand](https://api.jquerymobile.com/collapsible/#event-expand) event on the collapsible:

```
$(document).on("collapsibleexpand", "#coll2", function(event, ui)
{
    $("#2wrapper").load('some-external-program-content.cgi');
});
```

...By the way: it's good practice to avoid having IDs starting with a number (even if it's permitted in HTML5).

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I simultaneously found a similar answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399882/jquery-mobile-collapsible-expand-collapse-event and got it working using the expand event instead. Thank you very much also for your response. Thank you also for the guidance on leading numbers not being ideal. Cheers.